# Error Running simple mysql query

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am trying tu run a simple MYSQL query but it throws an error everytime.The query is

```
SELECT * FROM `user_recommendation` LEFT JOIN `tracking`
```

`user_recommendation` and `tracking` are in the same database and I am running the query under that.The error thrown is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2
```

I am unable to figure out the reason behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) a `LEFT JOIN` expects an `ON` or `USING` condition right after, which you left out in your SQL.

> **join_table:**
>
> table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_condition
>
> **join_condition:**
>
> ON conditional_expr
>
> | USING (column_list)

Answer (score 1):

What is your field that you want to join on that field

you should write your join queries like this :

```
 SELECT * FROM `user_recommendation` LEFT JOIN `tracking` on `user_recommendation`.id = `tracking`.id
```

Here we join 2 table on field named id 
so you should choose a filed that you want to make join on this